# Як правильно передавати українською мовою російські імена?

Tags: переклад, from-russian, власні-назви, іноземні-імена

Деякі українські видання (Український Тиждень, книжки видавництва "Темпора", деякі інші ЗМІ) передають російські імена шляхом транскрипції (напр. рос. Владимир - укр. Владімір, рос. Петр - укр. Пьотр, рос. Надежда - укр. Надєжда, рос. Олег - укр. Алєґ).

Натомість, інші просто вживають українські відповідники (Володимир Путін, Петро Перший, Надія Кадишева, Олег Кашин тощо).

Як правильно писати (і говорити) за чинним правописом?

Comment: Дуже цікаво! Тільки то у вас транслітерація, а не транскрипція, бо якщо передавати транскрипцією, то ж буде Алєґ, Нікалай, Сірґєй, Віктар, тощо. Особисто я саме за цей варіант. Але насправді тут у нас вибір з трьох варіянтів, а не з двох, як у вашому запитанні, 1. укр. відповідник (Олексій), 2. трансліт (Алексей), 3. транскрипція (Аліксєй).

Comment: Насправді, я мав на увазі саме транскрипцію, дарма що мій набір прикладів був недостатньо зрозумілим. Оновив запитання.

А щодо транслітерації - я ніде не бачив, щоб вона справді вживалася в поважних виданнях чи текстах.

Answer (score 12):

Інтуїтивно, російські прізвища повинні перекладатись як і інші іноземні прізвища та імена, тобто Пьотр, Владімір. На практиці можна побачити різні варіанти.

В [статті](http://www.radiosvoboda.org/a/24578064.html) на Радіо Свобода наводиться така історична довідка:

> Близькою до врегулювання цієї й інших нагальних правописних проблем
> була Національна комісія з питань правопису при Кабінеті Міністрів
> України. Робоча група, очолювана відомим мовознавцем, тодішнім
> директором Інституту української мови НАН України Василем Німчуком, у
> 1999 році підготувала зміни до чинного правопису, якими було
> врегульовано передавання власних імен. У грудні 2000 року ці зміни
> були підтримані Радою з питань мовної політики при Президенті України.
> На 15–16 лютого 2001 року було заплановано підсумкове засідання
> правописної комісії за участи діаспорних мовознавців, зокрема, вченого
> світової слави Юрія Шевельова.
>
> На жаль, втрутилася політика, велика політика. Відразу після
> завершення засідання Ради з питань мовної політики пропоновані зміни
> були віддані фактично на поталу деяким засобам масової інформації, в
> основному російськомовним, які організували «всенародне обговорення»,
> цинічно і безвідповідально перекручуючи зміст проекту правопису.
> Брехали, наприклад, що будемо писати «Хвранція», «самопер» (замість
> самоката), «Педір» (замість Федора), «на радіві» (замість на радіо) і
> т. п.
>
> Шабаш у деяких російськомовних виданнях призвів до того, що Президент
> Леонід Кучма скасував підсумкове засідання правописної комісії.
> Переконаний, що галас, здійнятий у ЗМІ, був спрямований на глушіння
> касетного скандалу, який почав розгортатися з кінця листопада 2000
> року. Таким робом зміни до правопису, необхідність яких є актуальною
> досі, впали жертвою шкурного політичного моменту.
>
> Як передавати російські (слов’янські) імена і прізвища
>
> У чинному правописі йдеться лише про прізвища [«§ 104. Фонетичні
> правила правопису слов’янських прізвищ»](http://www.madslinger.com/mova/pravopys-2007/rozdil-4.html#toc195). Це свідчить про те, що
> російські (й інші слов’янські) імена повинні відтворюватися за
> законами української мови. Але ж насправді далеко не всі слов’янські
> імена так відтворюються. Наприклад, чеський поет Петр Безруч (Petr
> Bezruč), польські поети Ян Кохановський (Jan Kochanowski) і Юліуш
> Словацький (Juliusz Słowacki) тощо.
>
> «Український правопис. (Проєкт найновішої редакції)» 1999 року за
> редакцією Василя Німчука [звернув увагу на цю прогалину](http://r2u.org.ua/pravopys/pravXXI/115.html): «За усталеною
> традицією імена та імена по батькові росіян і білорусів передаємо їх
> українськими відповідниками, пор.: Алекса́ндр Серге́евич Пу́шкин –
> Олекса́ндр Сергі́йович Пу́шкін, Михаи́л Шо́лохов – Михайло́ Шо́лохов,
> Петр Проску́рин – Петро́ Проскурі́н, Васи́лий Шукши́н – Васи́ль
> Шукши́н, Еле́на Образцо́ва – Оле́на Образцо́ва, Васі́ль Быкаў –
> Васи́ль Би́ков, Арка́дзь Жура́ўскі – Арка́дій Жура́вський, Яў́ге́н
> За́йцаў – Євге́н За́йцев, Уладзі́мір Ка́пцаў – Володи́мир Ка́пцев,
> Віта́ль Анічэнка – Віта́лій Аніче́нко, Анато́ль Ціто́ў – Анато́лій
> Тито́в».
>
> До речі, знаменитий харківський правопис, прийнятий консенсусом у 1927
> році і затверджений у вересні наступного року народним комісаром
> освіти Миколою Скрипником (т. зв. «скрипниківка»), не містить окремих
> правил відтворення російських імен – значить, склалася традиція і
> норма була неписаною. Підтвердження цього – виданий у Харкові 1929
> року, після ухвалення Всеукраїнською академією наук «Правописний
> словник» Григорія Голоскевича. Імена розсипані по всьому словнику, і
> там є не лише повні імена, але й зменшувальні: Володимир, Катерина,
> Катря, Марія, Марійка, Михайло, Михась, Наталя, Наталка, Олена, Петро,
> Петрусь тощо, але немає жодного російського відповідника.
>
> Відомо, що «скрипниківка» не проіснувала довго. Наступник Скрипника на
> посаді Володимир Затонський у постанові від 05.09.1933 р. «Про
> «Український правопис» вказав на «націоналістичні правила цього
> правопису, що орієнтували українську мову на польську, чеську
> буржуазну культуру». А голова комісії Андрій Хвиля підкреслив основний
> «гріх» цього правопису – створення бар’єрів між українською та
> російською мовами, у зв’язку з чим, серед іншого, «ліквідовано
> націоналістичні правила щодо правопису іншомовних слів».

Вікіпедія пропонує такий [варіант](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8F:%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83_%D0%B7_%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2):

> За усталеною традицією імена та імена по батькові **росіян і білорусів** передаємо їх українськими відповідниками
>
> Приклади: Алекса́ндр Серге́евич Пу́шкин — Олекса́ндр Сергі́йович Пу́шкін, Михаи́л Шо́лохов — Михайло́ Шо́лохов, Петр Проску́рин — Петро́ Проскурі́н, Васи́лий Шукши́н — Васи́ль Шукши́н, Еле́на Образцо́ва — Оле́на Образцо́ва, Васі́ль Быкаў — Васи́ль Би́ков, Арка́дзь Жура́ўскі — Арка́дій Жура́вський, Яў́ге́н За́йцаў — Євге́н За́йцев, Уладзі́мір Ка́пцаў — Володи́мир Ка́пцев, Віта́ль Анічэнка — Віта́лій Аніче́нко, Анато́ль Ціто́ў — Анато́лій Тито́в
>
> Передача іноземних прізвищ українською мовою:
>
> Щодо перекладу іноземних прізвищ, то **для слов'янських прізвищ** є окремі правила. Так російське `-ский`; польське, чеське `-ski` тощо перекладаються як `-ський`. Російське е передається:
>
> - **є**, якщо відповідає українському і (після приголосних) (Бєлов, Свєтлов);
> - **о**, якщо російською читається ё (Хрущов)
> - **е** в інших випадках (Ленін, Брежнєв) тощо.
>
> Імена **правлячих персон, монархів** які мають своїх відповідників в українській мові перекладаються незалежно від країни походження, а простих смертних ні.
>
> Приклади:
>
> - Принцеса **Діана** але співачка **Даяна Росс**;
> - Король Англії **Яків ІІ** але **Джеймс Бонд**;
> - Королі Англії **Генріх III, Генріх VII** і т.д. а всі інші **Генрі**;
> - Королі Франції **Генріх III** та ін. але для всіх інших - **Анрі**.

**Ред.** Ще одне [пояснення](http://lubavka.uamodna.com/articles/nashi-naymennya-imena-po-batjkovi-prizvyscha/) щодо написання російських імен та прізвищ:

> **Транскрибовані імена на зразок Артьом, Маріна, Наташа, Лєна (Альона), Діма суперечать українському правопису.**
>
> Петро Одарченко, "Про культуру укр-ї мови. Збірник статей" (Київ: Смолоскип. – 1997, с. 285):
>
> > В наш час у ЗМІ, не кажучи вже про побутове повсякденне мовлення, часто читаємо і чуємо жахливо спотворені імена людей: Татіана, Татяна, Тат яна, Пьотр Грігоренко, Наташа, Міхаїл, Міхаїл Горбачов, Павєл Літвінов, Ніколай Бухарін, патріарх Кіріл, Владімір Путін. Часто трапляються і такі дивовижні сполучення: Ольга Попов, Олена Худий, Тетяна Погорілий, Олександра Чабанівський і т. п. В українській мові існує давня традиція завжди писати і вимовляти українською мовою східнослов’янські імена людей", навіть якщо вони іншомовного походження: Петро, Микола, Тетяна, Павло, Михайло, Олександр.
>
> У Словнику Б.Грінченка, в Російсько-українському словнику О.Ізюмова (1930), в академічному Словнику власних імен людей (1976), у друкованих творах наших найкращих знавців мови (С. Єфремова, М. Зерова, А. Кримського та багатьох інших) – всюди власні імена людей пишуться українською мовою, якщо вони стосуються представників східнослов’янських народів.
>
> У "Кобзарі" Т. Шевченка читаємо імена московських державників: Петро, Катерина, Микола (а не Пьотр, Єкатєріна, Нікалай). В "Енциклопедії українознавства" (1955-84), у працях А.Кримського та інших виданнях читаємо: Олександр Пушкін, Олексій Шахматов, Олексій Толстой, Олександр Герцен, Володимир Ульянов, Микита Хрущов і т. д. Отже, треба писати не "Міхаїл Горбачов", а Михайло Горбачов. Так само, як ми пишемо Гоголь, а не Ґоґоль. Бо прізвище Гоголь походить від українського слова гоголь (назви дикого птаха родини качиних). Так само треба писати Горбачов, бо це прізвище походить від українського слова горбач, яке означає горбату людину. Російський відповідник – горбун. Звідси й російське прізвище Горбунов. (Перший звук у слові Горбунов вимовляється і пишеться як г, а не ґ, бо асоціюється з українським словом горб) (Петро Одарченко, "Про культуру укр-ї мови. Збірник статей" (Київ: Смолоскип. – 1997, – с.286).
>
> В російській мові існує правило перекладати українські імена російською мовою і вимовляти їх згідно з законами російської орфоепії. А тому імена і прізвища українських письменників і вчених по-російському звучать так: Міхаїл Кацюбінскій, Павєл Ґрабовскій, Владімір Сасюра, Нікалай Зєрофф, Пьотр Магіла, Тарас Ґріґорєвіч Шевчєнко.

Comment: Думаю, ця відповідь виграла б від скорочення щонайменше удвічі, а то і утричі. Чесно кажучи, настільки велику копіпасту важко читати.

Answer (score 2):

Вважаю, що правильно пишуть Дмітрій і Владімір. Ми ж не називаємо людину *Peter* *Петром*, так і тут: іншомовна власна назва не повинна перекладатись.

Comment: Я теж схиляюся до такого написання, але в питанні йдеться перш за все про чинний правопис.

Comment: Але короля Англії на ймення _James_ ми таки називаємо _Яковом_, тут не все так однозначно.

Comment: @YellowSky ви певно мали на увазі Jacob, а не James.

Comment: @Maksym - Хехе! Саме _James_! Я тут помилитися не міг, бо я вчитель англійської. Дивіться самі: https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Яків_I_(король_Англії)

Comment: @Maksym James походить від латинського Iacomus - звідки, очевидно, його можна гнути в обидва боки.

Comment: -1, хоча я цілком згоден з висновком. Відповіді виду «я вважаю, що…» мають ретельно обґрунтовуватися. В ідеальному випадку — це  посиланнями на поважні джерела. Інакше ми опинимося у ситуації, коли кілька користувачів «вважають» протилежні речі і не надають наукового пояснення. Наша власна думка може бути аргументом, але останнім із списку, не єдиним. Як завжди, я буду радий зняти свій «мінус», коли ви покращите цей допис.

Comment: @YellowSky дійсно! Це ж треба. Переклад James як Яків - це справді дуже дивний випадок.

Comment: @Maksym - Не такий вже й дивний, дивіться комент Sassa NF вище, то все так, в пізній латині «iacobus» викривили на «iacomus», звідси й пішло «James».

Answer (score 1):

## Переклад російських імен на українську

### § 144. Слов’янські прізвища та імена

> **Основні правила правопису прізвищ та імен інших слов’янських народів
> такі:**
>
> 1. Білоруські та російські імена за традицією не транслітеруємо, а передаємо українськими відповідниками: *Артéм*, *Микóла*, *Олексáндр*,
>    *Семéн*, *Вíра*, *Катерúна*, *Світлáна*; винятки тут становлять тільки
>    узвичаєні імена деяких білоруських письменників та діячів культури —
>    такі, як *Алéсь Адамóвич*, *Пятрýсь Брóвка*, *Рúгор Бородýлін* та ін.

Comment: Vkaźêtj ʒ́erelo. Jakśćo ne pomıljaju sja, [pravopıs](https://files.nas.gov.ua/PublicMessages/Documents/0/2021/01/210118223223523-1428.pdf#page=175) (2019).

Comment: Дякую за цитату. Втім, логіка цієї норми правопису виглядає дуже дивною. Навіщо робити винятки суто для _білоруських та російських_ імен? І потім в цьому винятку робити ще й окремий виняток суто для _білоруських_ імен, причому суто для білоруських _письменників та діячів культури_, і тільки для їхніх _узвичаєних імен_. Чому _Барадуліна_ можна назвати _Ригором_, а Путіна _Владіміром_ - не можна?

Виглядає як атавістичний колоніяльний підхід, що навмисне виокремлює росіян та білорусів як "частини триєдиного народу". Прикро що його реалізовано не колись в совку, а в 2019 (!) році.

Comment: @Maksym Східнослов'янські мови є спорідненими, переважна більшість слів в них мають спільну семантику, лексику і морфологію. Це незаперечний факт, обумовлений географічним чинником. Та маючи одне коріння, кожна з них розвивалася окремо і одні й ті самі сутності набули різних назв. Тому при перекладі на українську вживають відповідники. А щодо перекладу імен, то така норма є традиційною і існувала ще в Українському правописі редакції 1993 року.

Comment: @Skill хочете сказати, що польська мова значно дальша від української, аніж російська, що польські імена ми не перекладаємо, а російські - перекладаємо? Ось спростування цієї тези https://freeimage.host/i/HUzaX72 https://i.tyzhden.ua/content/photoalbum/2012/10_12/04/tyshenko/tyshenko.pdf

Comment: @Skill І твердження, що правопис 1993 року - "традиційний", дуже сумнівне, адже він, як значною мірою і чинний правопис, базований на сталінській наркомівці

Comment: @Maksym Я відповідаю як правильно перекладати відповідно до норм сучасного Правопису. На жаль, подібні до вашої публікації сучасних https://gazeta.ua/articles/istoriya-movi/_aki-yevropejski-movi-najblizhchi-mizh-soboyu/701681 не містять посилань на матеріали досліджень. На мою думку, справа в тому як мови поширювались разом з міграцією народів. Кириличні мови від Греції до Візантії, Балканів, на Русь і далі на північ та схід. Та латиниця з Риму на північ і північний схід вглиб Европи.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Не єсть відповідью, а розлогим коментарем. Як за чинним правописом — вже надана [відповідь](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/7226/585).</sub>

**Чеська** [дозволяїть](https://prirucka.ujc.cas.cz/?id=920) транслітеровати і траскрібовати. Лише декотрі назви [не підпадають](https://prirucka.ujc.cas.cz/?id=926) під це, де радше єсть наявний вплив гинших мов-посередниць, бо наприклад *Київ* був би в *перекладах* шчось як *Kyjův*, а не *Kyjev* (чи старїшого *Kijev*).

**Словацька** [маїть](https://www.juls.savba.sk/ediela/psp2000/psp.pdf#page=43) подібну гісторію, тільки етімолоґічно там було би *Kyjôv*. Можна хіба шчо окремо зазначити, шчо після початку повномасштабної війни декотрі — як [*Denník N*](https://dennikn.sk/2781783/kyjev-je-kyjiv-a-v-denniku-n-ho-tak-aj-budeme-pisat/), [*SITA Slovenská tlačová agentúra*](https://sita.sk/eu-pomoze-ukrajine-vstat-z-popola-vyhlasila-von-der-leyenova-v-kyjeve/), [*Týždeň*](https://www.tyzden.sk/svet/82394/ukrajina-online-ruski-generali-klamu-putina-kremel-nedokaze-branit-vlastnu-krajinu-tvrdi-prigozin/) ітд — почали писати *Kyjiv*. Шчось подібне маїмо і ми, коли декотрі почали писати наприклад *Бєлгород* проти *Білгород*.

З **словенскою** мовою трохи сладнїше через [внутрїшнї зміни](https://sl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pravopis_8.0): там правопис переводять суто на елетронну моделу, тобто оновюють і випускають по частинам, а не весь. Це навіть відображено на «назві» правописа: *Pravopis 8.0*. Прикольна ідея, бо я якраз хотїв і хочу, аби наш правопис був шчось на зразок [ґіт](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git)-сістемі, де можна було бачити хронолоґію і кожну зміну. До записа мов, шчо не на латинському письмі, шче не дійшли. Тож якшчо брати старїше, то там [єсть](https://fran.si/134/slovenski-pravopis/datoteke/Pravopis_Pravila.pdf#page=179) майже така сама структура: транслітерація → одомашення, і, звісно декотрі винятки як:

> Rusko obliko ukrajinskega imena ohranimo, če je pri nas uveljavljena, npr. *Kíjev*, *Lvôv*, *Hárkov*, *Černobíl*, *Zaporóžje*.

**Хорватська**, як і чеська, маїть і траскріпцію, і транслітерацію. Теж були винятки, але [дозволяїть](http://pravopis.hr/pravilo/pisanje-imena/47/) писати *Kijiv* і не лише шче з початку московсько-української війни, тобто з 2014 року.

> S obzirom na to da su i osobna i ostala imena iz ukrajinskoga u hrvatski često ušla prema ruskome izgovoru, istovrijedno je i njihovo pisanje prema transfonemizacijskim pravilima koja vrijede za prenošenje [ukrajinske ćirilice](http://pravopis.hr/uploads/5-o7.pdf) na hrvatsku latinicu: *Čornobilj, Kijiv, Ljviv, Dnjipro, Dnjipropetrovsk, Harkiv, Sergij Bubka, Andrij Ševčenko*, a za nova imena mjesta i osobna imena preporučuje se transfonemizacija iz ukrajinskoga jezika. Za znanstvene potrebe (zemljovidi, filološka istraživanja i sl.) moguće je primjenjivati i transliteraciju.

**Північномакедонська** шчедро [заготовила](https://pravopis.mk/sites/default/files/Pravopis-2017.PDF#page=271) таблицї і правила для різних мов, чим мене добре вразила. Шчодо українскьої, там я помітив помилку:

> Групата *ню* се предава со *њу*: *Тельнюк – Тељњук, Романюк – Ромањук,
> Севернюк – Северњук, Синюк – Сињук, Мартинюк – Мартињук, Корнющенко – Корњушченко*.

Але можна побачити таке:

> Буквите *я* и *ю*, освен по *н* и *л*, се предаваат со *ја*, односно со *ју*: … *Степанюк – Степанјук*.

Де *освен* це *крім*. Але загалом, тут транслітерація [з врахованнєм фонетіки, бо письмо банально не даїть змоги], прізвишча на *ий* пристосовують ся під пн. македонську. Знов з винятками:

> Украинските сопствени имиња не добиваат наша форма: *Петро – Петро, Дмитро – Дмитро, Яків – Јакив, Федір – Феɡир, Павло – Павло, Олена – Олена*.
>
> Но: *Ничипір – Ничипор, Хведір – Хвеɡор* (зашто првобитното о се јавува во сите други форми). Така и: *Львів – Лавов, Київ – Киев*.

Болгарський правопис не знайшов. [Сербську](https://sr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0_%D1%98%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0), [чорногорську](https://hr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pravopis_crnogorskoga_jezika) і боснійську [шчо справедливо декотрима зазначено як одну мову, включно з хорватською] не розглядав, хоча, не заперечую, можуть мати відмінні або відсутні стандарти запису гиншомовних слів. Як в московській і білоруській можна не розписовати, бо там десь як тут — переклад, оскільки була політіка зближення [*ч.* знишчення] мов до єдиної правильної — московської.

Лишила ся **польська**, котра [маїть](https://sjp.pwn.pl/zasady/78-Transliteracja-i-transkrypcja-wspolczesnego-alfabetu-ukrainskiego;629710.html) траслітерацію і транскріпцію, але з поширеною практікою [спольшчення](https://sjp.pwn.pl/zasady/78-C-Polszczenie-ukrainskich-nazw-wlasnych;629713.html): декотрі ґеографічні назви і насамперед наростки як *-ий*, *-ич* та *-ів*, але без спольшчення самого корня [хоча і тут єсть винятки]:

> Należy zwrócić uwagę na to, że polszczymy tylko zakończenia ukraińskich nazwisk; ich pozostała część zachowuje właściwości fonetyczne oryginału, toteż piszemy: *Łewycki, Szaszkewycz, Ziłynski* (a nie: *Lewicki, Szaszkiewicz, Ziłyński*). W przypadku nazwisk historycznych czy znanych w wersji polskiej możemy stosować wersję polską (także w transkrypcji): *Chmielnicki, Rudnicki, Wiszniowiecki, Ziłyński*.

Ради зауваження: московська і польська мають найбільш етімолоґічні правописи з поміж словянських мов, втч української. Тому наявність опції перекладу в згаданих мовах може бути не скільки арґументом, а і контрарґументом. А більшість словянських мов якраз за несильну транскріпцію під свою вимову, і в декотрих випадках [переважно де потрїбна точність] за транслітерацію.

---

Також треба враховати **проблеми транскріпції**.

Чи треба мати на увазї редукцію голосних і оглушення приголосних — тобто **алофонів**? Моя ж думка, шчо крашче нї, бо це ускладнюватийму правопис [і можливо потребу знати московську] і сильнїше ламатийме корнї слів. Пак московська мова теж маїть несталий наголос. Достатньо брати лише основні звуки, шчо вже відносно і робимо наприклад з нїмецькою.

Друга проблема радше лежить на українській абетцї, шчо дозволяїть ставити *ь* і *апостроф* ледь не тупо будь-де, а тому можить виникати бажання писати шчось на зразок *Н'ю* і згаданих тут *Пьотр* і *Бєлгород* [за вимовою взагалї як *Бєлґорат*], хоча за **українською вимовою** [пропустимо діскуцію про потрїбність апострофа, [наприклад](/q/7130/585)] то маїть бути радше як *Нью*, *Пйотр* і *Б'єлґород*. Гинші згадані вишче словянські мови [крім московської і білоруської] такого не можуть дозволити через відповідний склад абетки. На жаль чи ради справедливостї, декотрі подібні слова як *Горький* (єдиний виняток), *кювет*, *пюре* ітд — вже давно унормовані правописом і узвичаїли ся, тому для декотрих це вже може бути як шчось належне, а тому така проблема ставати діскуційним питаннєм. Можна хіба шчо зазначити, шчо правопис поки жорстко забороняїть писати *шь*, *пь* ітп без наступних голосних, однак саме письмо надаїть таку змогу писати і сприймати, тож… недивно, шчо місцями така практіка теж існуїть.

Answer (score -2):

Власні, географічні, адміністративні назви та імена варто транскрибувати. Тобто записувати так, як вони звучать місцевою мовою.

Бєларусь. Мєнск. Расія. Масква.

Допускаються відмінності від оригінального звучання через пом'якшення голосних та приголосних.
Наприклад: можна писати Дойчланд або Дойчлянд, Полска або Польска, Зміцєр або Зьміцєр(це бєларуське ім'я, аналог Дмитра).

Comment: Вітаємо на сайті Ukrainian Language.SE! Будь ласка, почитайте про [наші критерії](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/36), за якими ми оцінюємо хороші відповіді. Для того щоб зробити вашу відповідь кращою додайте посилання на поважні джерела, що підтверджують вашу думку.