# Звідки пішло пристосовувати власні імена титулових осіб?

Tags: власні-назви, історія-мови

Після знакової подїї — смертьи Елізабети Ⅱ — знову постали суперечки як записувати обране власне імє: *Карл Ⅲ* чи *Чарл(ь)з Ⅲ*. Менї цїкава причина не як *правило*, а *явище*, тобто: з якої мови таке перебрали, якщо таке було, так завжди чи як довго таке було ітд.

Щодо самого правила, то часто наводять підручник І. В. Корунець «Теорія і практика перекладу» (Аспектний переклад), під редакцією О. І. Тереха, що затверджено Міністерством освіти України в 2000 році і котрого ві вільному доступі, схоже, не знайти. Ще цїкавіше: правопис про це нічого не каже чи згадує, або я не дуже знаходжу. Причому це правило, схоже, робе лише для декотрих мов, бо нп. еспанський король [*Хуан Карлос Ⅰ*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81_I) залишає ся без змін.

Comment: Відповідь на [це запитання](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/13/8) пояснює також і англомовні власні імена, у тому числі королівських осіб. Коротко — правила вимагають писати *Карл*, тому що таким є звичайне паспортне ім'я (щоправда, рідкісне).

Comment: @BeBraveBeLikeUkraine на справдї не пояснює. Там про словянські, тут саме про монархів ітп. Там згадано правило (про що не просив) від Вікіпедії — причому без жодних джерел і з суперечностями до себе (приклад Хуана Карлоса).

Comment: [Цікавий огляд аргументів за і проти Карла](https://www.unian.ua/world/charlz-iii-chi-karl-iii-yak-pravilno-ukrajinskoyu-11972895.html). І гарне питання до підручника: "Якщо, як пише підручник, "власні назви титулованих осіб перекладаються", то чому ми називали принца Чарльзом? "Принц" - це титул. Вчора Чарльз змінив титул, а не ім'я."